# My "\b" character prints a blank space rather than deletes to the left. Is this normal?

Tags: ascii, backspace

I'm trying to replace or delete a previously printed line so I'm trying to use /b. When I enter:
Print "p\by\bt\bh\bo\bn"

It prints out "p y t h o n" rather than replacing the characters.  Am I using the special char incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

That works just fine, in a normal environment:

```
>>> print "p\by\bt\bh\bo\bn"
n
```

The first thing I would do would be to check what it was actually outputting. If you're under a UNIX-like OS, you can put the following line into a script called `qq.py`:

```
print "p\by\bt\bh\bo\bn"
```

The run it, converting the output to a hex dump:

```
pax> python qq.py | od -xcb
0000000    0870    0879    0874    0868    086f    0a6e
          p  \b   y  \b   t  \b   h  \b   o  \b   n  \n
        160 010 171 010 164 010 150 010 157 010 156 012
0000014
```

That shows that the output does indeed consist of the correct characters. If you see that, then there's probably something wrong with your terminal setting in that the backspace is not set up correctly, in which case it's probably an environmental issue outside the scope of programming.

Comment: I'm using python 2. Sorry bout that. When I enter that line I end up getting. "P y t h o n" rather than " n "